# Какой алгоритм использовать для сопоставления множества оплат/поставок?

Tags: алгоритм

Есть 2 таблицы

Первая это документы поступления товаров

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вторая документы оплаты поступлений

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем не известно какая оплата на какой документ поступления.

**Правила:**
 -организация всегда сначала получает товар от поставщика, а затем оплачивает его; 
 - одна поставка может быть оплачена одним или несколькими платежами, начиная со следующего дня после дня поставки в 
   течение любого срока;
 - одна операция оплаты может относиться только к одной операции поставки

**Задача:**
  К каждой операции поставки товара нужно подобрать набор операций оплаты, обеспечивающих полную оплату каждой поставки, но без переплаты.

Если не удаётся найти вариант распределения оплат по поставкам, полностью удовлетворяющий заданным условиям, тогда нужно предложить вариант, который закрывает наибольшее количество поставок.

Comment: Существует. Увы - это полный перебор. В каких-то случаях можно пытаться динамическое программирование использовать, в общем - приближенные решения искать. [Кое-что для начала](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422921/multiple-subset-sum-calculation)

Comment: спасибо, посмотрю

Comment: Наиболее разумный алгоритм - это не страдать фигнёй, а вести текущий баланс. Приходы и расходы перемешиваются (у расходов меняется знак суммы на отрицательный) и сортируются по дате (для совпадающих дат - сначала приходы), после чего для каждой записи считается сумма с накоплением. Бухгалтеры - не идиоты, и баланс не от фонаря придумали.

Comment: А если ну очень упёрлось раскидать именно оплаты поштучно - добро пожаловать в мир очень стандартной (и, к сожалению, NP-полной) задачи одномерного раскроя.